# jQuery Autocomplete Filtration does not works?

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to use jqueryUI autocomplete feature where the available tags will be fetched from the backend source. Here is my code.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="span4 pull-right">
    Search : <input type="text"  id="search" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

**js code**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/dashboard/search"
    });
});
</script>
```

**django views.py**

```
def search(request):
    availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang"];
    data = simplejson.dumps(availableTags)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

My availabletags are returned but filtering of availableTags did not work. It shows the complete list of availableTags. Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: That question was added by me only and it has  different context. If possible provide with a solution rather than tagging it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def search(request):
    availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang"];
    data = simplejson.dumps(availableTags)
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Still the same problem.